# Summing a number from a random number source

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm just starting to learn flink and trying to build a very basic toy example which sums an integer over time and periodically prints the total sum so far

I've created a random number generator source class like this:

```java
// RandomNumberSource.java
public class RandomNumberSource implements SourceFunction<Integer> {
    public volatile boolean isRunning = true;
    private Random rand;

    public RandomNumberSource() {
        this.rand = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Integer> ctx) throws Exception {
        while (isRunning) {
            ctx.collect(rand.nextInt(200));
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it generates a random number every 1 second

Now how would I go about summing the number that's being generated?

```java
// StreamJob.java
public class StreamingJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<Integer> randomNumber = env.addSource(new RandomNumberSource());

        // pseudo code:
        // randomNumber
        //    .window(Time.seconds(5))
        //    .reduce(0, (acc, i) => acc+i) // (initial value, reducer)
        //    .sum()


        // execute program
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Random Number Sum Aggregation");
    }
}
```

I've added pseudo code to explain what I'm trying to do. i.e every 5 seconds, perform a sum of all the numbers and print it out.

I feel like I'm missing something in my approach and might need some guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window` operator is used for keyed streams. You should instead use `windowAll` for this task. Here's the snippet:

```
    randomNumber
            .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
            .sum(0)
            .print()
            .setParallelism(1);
```

Also check [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html) for reference on various window considerations.